# Does compressed data expose information about non-compressed data when encrypted together?

Tags: encryption, side-channel-attack, compression

I know that compressing data before encrypting it can cause a [compression oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_attack) attack such as in the [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) and [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) attacks, but if only part of the data is compressed, e.g. non-user controlled and/or non-sensitive data, and the user controlled/sensitive data is not compressed, but they are then encrypted together, does the compressed portion affect the security of the non-compressed portion?

- encryption(compression("mix of user controlled and sensitive data")) = vulnerable
- encryption(compression("only non-user controlled and/or non-sensitive data") + "user controlled and sensitive data") = ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the reason for the side channel attack is that data like `"username=alice&password=swordfish&evil_value=sword"` compresses better together since the evil attacker controlled data `sword` matches part of the secret value `swordfish`. If then attacker guesses `swordf` the compressed data will stay the same size. If they guess `swordg` the compressed data will be larger. In this way they can find the value through repeated compression oracle calls.

Note that only the attacker cares only about the length of the compressed data which is unchanged by encryption(note:padding can complicate this but stream ciphers don't change length). So encryption isn't the problem, only whether `length(plaintext)` changes.

`length(compress(secret || untrusted))` leaks information about `secret`

`length(compress(secret) || compress(untrusted))` does not since it uses two independent calls to `compress()`.

Your second example of `length(compress(untrusted) || secret)` also does not since the call to `compress()` does not include any secret data.

### Security boundary aware compression

One neat way to solve these sorts of security problems would be to have a security aware compression algorithm. Choose a special flag string like `"compbound"` that indicates a security boundary in the compressed data and have the compression algorithm look for these boundaries and make no matches across them. It's also useful to have that string survive compression intact so that repeated compression doesn't leak information.

There's some other variants like an open/close tag that protects a small string. Useful for protecting things like CSRF tokens embedded in HTML without hurting compression of the surrounding HTML. Any secret values can be bracketed by these tags to prevent compression oracle attacks from leaking them.